# Norm of a Matrix-vector product

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, products, vectors

Suppose I have vector $\vec x \in \mathbb R^n$ and matrix $\mathbf M$ of dimension $m\times n$. Is there an alternative expression for $\lVert \mathbf M \cdot \vec x \lVert$ that includes $\lVert \vec x \lVert$?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to express $\lVert\mathbf M\cdot\vec x\lVert$ that somehow includes the value $\lVert\vec x\lVert$? Analogous to how $\lVert k\cdot\vec v\lVert=k\cdot\lVert\vec v\lVert$ for any scalar $k$ and vector $\vec v$.

Comment: What do you mean by "includes"?

Comment: I mean the value $\lVert\vec x\lVert$ is included on the expression. For example, if the expression were $\lVert\mathbf M\cdot\vec x\lVert=\lVert\mathbf M\lVert\cdot\lVert\vec x\lVert$ (which is not true, but gives an idea for the kind of expression I'm looking for).

Comment: Well, yes, there is, but probably this isn't what you look for:)
$$\|Mx\|=\|Mx\|+\|x\|-\|x\|\,.$$

Comment: @Disousa Ok. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Berci Yes, it's definitely not what I'm looking for xD

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. There's no equality that looks like this, no. I'll give a reason below.
2. There's an inequality: 
   $$
   \| M \cdot x \| \le \|M \| ~ \| x \|.
   $$
   But when you see the definition of $\|M\|$, it's pretty disappointing:
   $$
   \|M \| = \max_{\|x\| = 1}  \| M\cdot x \|. 
   $$

What about the first part? Well, look at 
$$M = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$.

The result of multiplying this by $[1, 0]^t$ has length 1; the result of multiplying it by $[0, 1]^t$ has length zero. And each of these vectors has length one. So you're looking for something that can multiply 1 to get 0 in one case, and can multiply 1 to get 1 in the other. There ain't no such thing. Two dimensions are more complicated than one, and matrix multiplication is more complicated than scalar multiplication.

Comment: What is that inequality called?

Comment: It doesn't have a name that I know of...it's a straightforward consequence of the definition of the matrix norm.